# Jquery Select 2 on append

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to append a div which has 2 multi select and selection is based on select2. I have appended this div and the multi select is working on appended div selection but its disabling on original div selection. What can I do to solve this?

Here is my code

```
   <div class="ps-slt-item-container">
   <div class="parent-content">
   <div class="card ps-slt-item-content form-element-card">
 <div class="mb-3">
 <label for="product_feature" class="form-label">@lang('package::plan.product feature')</label>
 <select name="features[]" id="features" class="form-select bgw-multiple-select" multiple>
 <option value="">--- {{ __('package::plan.choose product features for this plan') }} ---</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
 <label for="product_plugin" class="form-label">@lang('package::plan.product plugin')</label>
<select name="plugins[]" id="plugins" class="form-select bgw-multiple-select" multiple>
<option value="">--- {{ __('package::plan.choose allowed plugin for this plan') }} ---</option>
</select>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is my jquery code

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.bgw-multiple-select').select2({
                tags:true,
                allowClear: true,
                width:'100%'
            });
        });

        var card_length = $(".ps-slt-item-container").find(".ps-slt-item-content").length;
$(document).on("click", ".addNewPlan", function(){
    card_length++;
   var card = $(this).closest(".ps-slt-item-container").find(".parent-content").find(".ps-slt-item-content").clone();
    var card_counter = card.find(".card-header").find(".counter").text(card_length);
   $(".ps-slt-item-container").append(card);

    $('.bgw-multiple-select').select2({
        tags:true,
        allowClear: true,
        width:'100%'
    });
    $('.bgw-multiple-select').next().next().remove();
```